# create a new list from 2 other list with conditions

Tags: r, list, function

I have two large list (more than 10 elements) and I want to apply a function in one of the the list based on the other one. So one of my list has elements with temperature (list1) and the other has elements with heat transfer coefficient (list2). I want to apply the function `(x*0.6/k)` where x is the values in list2 and k will vary according to list1. For example if temperature is equal 20C, k is 0.02514.

I am going to use one element of each list as a data frame here to better illustrate what I am trying to do.

```
list1_element1 <- data.frame("0" = c(20, 150, 120),
                             "10" = c(20, 800, 120)) 

list2_element2 <- data.frame("0" = c(8, 10, 6),
                             "10" = c(10, 9, 8))
```

here is the conditions for k

```
if 0 < X <= 20 in list 1, k=0.02514
if 100 < X <= 200 in list 1 = 100, k=0.03095
if 700 < X <= 800 in list 1 = 800, k=0.07037
```

Applying the function x*0.6/k in list 2, this is the result I am looking for

```
list3_element1<- data.frame("0" = c(190.93, 193.86, 116.31 ),
                     "10" = c(238.66, 76.73, 155.08))
```

To clarify, I want to apply the function in `list2_element2` using the conditions of k based on `list1_element1`. The same I want to do for element2 (apply the function in `list2_element2` with k based on `list1_element1`) and so on.

I hope I was clear about what I am trying to do. So any help is very much appreciated because I am not sure from where to start. Thank you.

Comment: (1) You intend to name your columns `"0"` and `"10"`, but R doesn't allow that by default, naming them instead `"X0"` and `"X10"`. Is this an issue? If you really must have number-leading column names, add `check.names=FALSE`. (2) We have `list1_element1` and `list2_element2`, and then you say *"element1 of list2"*, and *"element 2 in list1"*. I'm confused what we should be working on.

Comment: I made some changes/corrections to your question based on my answer matching your expected output.

Comment: 1) My data has the columns names as angles (i.e. numbers) when I load the data in R, it is assigned X for each column name, but that is not a problem. 2) About the elements, I have the same number of elements in both lists to apply the function and create a new list I want to use the "pair" of elements of each list, for example list1_element1 with list2_element1; list1_element2 with list2_element2; etc. Thank you for the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a data frame with the mapped coefficients. I used a nested ifelse statement since you only have 3 conditions. `cut()` can be used for efficiency and multiple conditions.

```
d1 <- data.frame(ifelse(list1_element1 <= 20, 0.02514, 
                        ifelse(list1_element1 > 100 & list1_element1 <= 200, 0.03095, 
                               ifelse(list1_element1 > 700 & list1_element1 <= 800, 0.07037, NA))))

mapply(function(x, y)x * 0.6 / y, list2_element2, d1)

           X0       X10
[1,] 190.9308 238.66348
[2,] 193.8611  76.73725
[3,] 116.3166 155.08885
```